# Round icon to the marker in Google map v2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have implemented google maps in my android app. I have two questions related to markers.

**Question 1:** How to get a round profile image marker? i.e I would like to get roud image icon rather than square image icon in the mapmarker?

I am getting the list of lat, long, and profiepic link from a particular URL and loading them using Async. On Post execute I have
    implemented a for loop

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++)
        {
            userName = nameList.get(i).getName();
            lati = nameList.get(i).getLati();
            longi = nameList.get(i).getLongi();
            photoUrl = nameList.get(i).getImage();

            gotoLocation(Double.parseDouble(lati), Double.parseDouble(longi), userName, photoUrl, ZOOMVALUE);
        }
    }
```

I am loading the image using picasso library to the marker:

```
    private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, String name, String url, float zoom)
    {
       final String uname = name; 
       curlat = lat;
       curlong = lng;

      Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url).resize(100, 100).into(new Target() 
      { 
        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) 
        {
            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(curlat, curlong)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.profilepic)).title(uname);
            markerforfriends = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);          
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap b, LoadedFrom arg1) 
        {

            bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(b);

            if(b != null)
            {
                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(curlat, curlong)).icon(bitmapMarker).title(uname);
            }
            else
            {
                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(curlat, curlong)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.profilepic)).snippet(uname);
            }

            markerforfriends = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);                    

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) 
        {

        }
      });

    }
```

I tried the following:

```
    CircleOptions circle=new CircleOptions();
    circle.center(ll).fillColor(Color.LTGRAY).radius(1);
    googleMap.addCircle(circle);
```

This circles the current location but not the image?

**Question 2:** The above markers don't pop up always (not stable)? if I refersh the map it comes up properly? What could be wrong here? Is it because I am loading them using piccasso library? Is there different method to load the image from URL and them to marker?

Comment: where is bitmapMarker defined?  I am not sure this is a weak reference/ garbage collection issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved **QUESTION 1 Part..** Since I am using picasso this became very useful for me to draw a circle icon.

```
Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
.borderColor(Color.WHITE)
.borderWidthDp(3)
.cornerRadiusDp(30)
.oval(false)
.build();
```

used RoundedTransformationBuilder Library!

Thanks to the creator of https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView!

Thought this will be useful for others if they want to have something similar to MY QUESTION 1..

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue. See here: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/308

According to Jake Wharton, don't declare Target as anonymous, as it gets garbage collected. Declare it as a private within your activity for example. See if that works.

On a separate file:

```
public class DummyTarget implements Target
{
    public String uname;
    //etc....

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom from) {
     // you codes....      

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
     // your codes....

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
}
```

Somewhere, declare it

```
private target = new DummyTarget();
```

And in your Picasso call(s):

```
private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, String name, String url, float zoom)
    {
       final String uname = name; 
       curlat = lat;
       curlong = lng;

       // set dummy target
       target.uname = uname;
       // etc...

      Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url).resize(100, 100).into(target);
```

Comment: @ alpinescrambler: Thanks for the quick reply? Can you let me know what needs to be done for that? I mean is there an example?

Comment: Inside target the username, bitmap, curlat and curlong are dynamic. so how can I declare it?

Comment: Maybe you can declare in a separate class file, a class that extends Target. The class also have extra properties for username, curlat, etc... In your activity declare a List of this class , and populate it with new instances of your class during your for-loop. This way, a reference is held for each "Target" class kind. Personally, I had dealt with Picasso before in similar issues as you have, and I gave up. I used Volley instead. https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728

Comment: I think the sample code you had put already would help me. Can you post that code again?

Comment: OK I posted an updated one... Not sure if that compiles, but try to work with it. Good luck!

Comment: Do you think Volley can upload Bitmap images into google maps

Comment: I've used it to load into a dynamic MarkerInfoWindow - info window that shows a downloaded photo/thumbnail. So I think it can be done with markers too.

Comment: Let me check on the volley part? Can you help me with other question?

Comment: @alphinescrambler: I tried what you recommended but couldn't get the pic? I couldn't get a solution for Volley too.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just load into "this"

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url).resize(100, 100).into(this);
```

and then have the current class implement Target

```
    public class YourClass implements Target {

        private ArrayList<BitMap> bitMaps;

    private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, String name, String url, float zoom)  {
       final String uname = name; 
       curlat = lat;
       curlong = lng;
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url).resize(100, 100).into(this);
    }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
            bitMaps.add(bitmap);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {


        }

    }
```

Comment: I missed that you are looping thru, so you would need to save each bit map somewhere, maybe in an arrayList?

Comment: can you hlep with the other question?

Comment: what is "ll" in your code,  it should be the same lat/lng as the marker you are placing, no?

Comment: Yep. that is right. I realized that after running the code. I am trying have round profile image icon rather square one?

Comment: Circles and Icons are two different things.  If you want your icon to be a circular border of say a photo, I would think you should just have the bitmap setup that way.  create the bitmap with a transparent circular boarder, or download it an process it on the device, but I don't think there is anyway to do that in gmaps directly.   A circle is more like an overlay, i use them to indicate the accuracy of a gps fix for example.

Comment: Any idea in how to round the bitmap image icon and show them in the map?

Comment: @ nPN I actually tried what ever you recommended in the same map fragment class. But I still have the same issue.

Comment: i would print some data to logcat to try and see what is going on. print sonething in the onBitmapLoaded, and something different in onBitmapFailed.  Then you can tell if it is due to the bitmap not loading the first time due to an error,  or if onBitmapLoaded is just not being called (ie the object holding the callback has been garbage collected)